# how do i code a RemoveCallsToGCKeepAlive exception to be picked up in FxCop?

Tags: .net, fxcop

I am testing FxCop automation and want to validate it is screening and catching certain rules. I want to make a dll that will trigger the RemoveCallsToGCKeepAlive error in FxCop.

I have the following code but it is not triggering the RemoveCallsToGCKeepAlive rule at all. what am i doing wrong?

```
static void Gen_RemoveCallsToGCKeepAlive(){
    string str = "";
    GC.KeepAlive (str);
}
```

how can i trip this FxCop Rule?

Comment: Does FxCop find any other rule violations in your DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the stand-alone FxCop, your code isn't checked for the same reason of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662211/how-to-you-code-a-avoidcallingproblematicmethods-exception-to-be-picked-up-in-fxc/4679742#4679742).

The RemoveCallsToGCKeepAlive is a Relialibity rule so FxCop doesn't support it.

**UPDATE**

You can use this rule in FxCop, if you copy VS2010 code analysis rules to FxCop Rules directory. For more detail, refer to [my answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662211/how-to-you-code-a-avoidcallingproblematicmethods-exception-to-be-picked-up-in-fxc/4679742#4679742).